# Create embeded docs mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I've the following mongoose schema:

```
'use strict';

const PostSchema = new Schema({
    description: require('../fields/description'),
    image: require('../fields/image'),
    createdAt: require('../fields/createdAt'),
    location: Location,
    owner: require('../fields/owner') }, {
    toObject: {
        virtuals: true,
        getters: true,
        setters: true
    },
    toJSON: {
        virtuals: true,
        getters: true,
        setters: true
    } });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

LocationSchema.js

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const LocationSchema = new Schema({
    description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
    point:{
    type: [Number],
    index: '2d',
    required: true
},
    createdAt:{
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: new Date()
}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Location', LocationSchema);
```

and when i will restart my nodejs server  i've the following error message:

> TypeError: Undefined type `Model` at `location`   Did you try nesting
>   Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.

Someone know how to solve this ?

Comment: Could you please add up more details here. About what `Location` is.

Comment: I add LocationSchema

Comment: is this your question = > your post collection have a location key and those locations are saved in different collection called location?

Answer (score 0):

your error here represents that you have not given reference to location key in your post collection if you want to give location id to your post collection you have to provide reference to your collection.

example:

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  location: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'location' }]
});
```